# How to convert from printf to print?

Tags: java, printf

How would I convert `System.out.printf("%3s", "");`to a `.print()` in Java? And also

`System.out.printf("%3d\n", (i - startDay));`.

Comment: Are you using a version of Java before 1.5, when `printf` became available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`String.format(String format, Object... args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.print(String.format("%3s", ""));
```

And:

```
int i = 50;
int startDay = 20;
System.out.print(String.format("%3d\n", (i - startDay)));
```

Comment: Thank you! but what does the d and the s mean? Sorry.

Comment: `d` specifies that The result is formatted as a decimal integer and `s` specifies that  the result is obtained by invoking `arg.toString()`.  Check out the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class for details.